# How does MetaMask know the name of the contract function you're calling?

Tags: metamask, wallets, abi

When you interact with a smart contract and, instead of the name of the function you're calling, MetaMask only outputs "CONTRACT INTERACTION", is this because the contract you're interacting with hasn't been verified at the Block Explorer you've configured MetaMask to use for the blockchain when adding the network?

Second question: given that only the contract bytecode (and not the ABI, too) is uploaded to the blockchain when a contract is deployed, how does MetaMask know to output the name of the function you're calling in a human-readable form? Does it fully trusts the Block Explorer in terms of the ABI of the contract a MetaMask user interacts with - or, maybe, queries this information from someplace else it trusts?

[image]

Comment: There are repositories of common method names like https://github.com/ethereum-lists/4bytes/, for verified contracts there's also obviously public ABI on etherscan, not sure what exactly MM is using.

Comment: @kfx, if the function signature included in the tx can easily be reverse-engineered to the name of the function, why don't wallets always show us the function name? For example, I've just tried initiating a swap via ParaSwap on Ethereum, Polygon and Fantom - and the function was only identified as "CONTRACT INTERACTION" on Ethereum (while it correctly appeared as "simple swap" on the other two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple: you need to register it.

From MetaMask docs: https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/display/method-names

> MetaMask uses the Ethereum Signature Database to display method names on the confirmation screen. For many common method names, such as token methods, this allows MetaMask to look up the method names by their method signature. However, sometimes you're using a method that isn't in that database, and MetaMask simply displays Contract Interaction to the user.

> To register your contract's method names so they show in the MetaMask interface, submit each method's signature to the Ethereum Signature Database.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you for the precise answer, Ricardo!

Answer (score 0):

Answering in order:

> is this because the contract you're interacting with hasn't been
> verified at the Block Explorer you've configured MetaMask to use for
> the blockchain when adding the network?

No, it isn’t because of that. And as far as I’m aware, you don’t need to ‘configure MetaMask’ to use a block explorer. Metamask is essentially just a wallet that allows you to connect with different chains.

> how does MetaMask know to output the name of the function you're
> calling in a human-readable form?

Since the ABI only includes function selectors (first 4 bytes of keccak hash of the function signature) that are available to interact with (I.e not `private` or `internal` functions), it is only these functions that even have a chance of being decoded, by anything like MetaMask **or** a block explorer. Furthermore the functions and arguments that are available to decode are only those that are either included in the `topics` or `data` of the transactions `tx.receipt`, usually emitted specifically by `events`.

Function names can thereafter be derived from their signature, available in the bytecode, via web3 js (or similar), via a schema. This is how the front ends we see find these function names.

So, if you see ‘CONTRACT INTERACTION` via metamask, it could be relating to any function, call, fallback or receive function bing executed on the contract you interacted with. The only way to find out about what happened in that tx is to go to a block explorer with the transaction hash and inspect these datas.

Hope that helps

Comment: MetaMask does ask you for a "Block explorer URL" when adding a network manually. However, this field is optional. I've just tried removing the Block explorer URL from the definition of a Network in MetaMask - and this didn't affect the way the function name you're interacting with appears (or doesn't appear) in the MetaMask pop-up. Which settles my first question.

Comment: Why are you talking about ABI if it's not a part of the contract data stored on the blockchain (only the contract bytecode is)?..

Comment: ABI is the bytecode in a different format - ‘application binary interface’ allows us mortals to interact with the blockchain’s native bytecode. They are in a sense synonymous

Comment: So, essentially, the bytecode is the only thing that's needed for any frontend or wallet to decode and properly show us the signature of the function (in a way we could read it) we're interacting with, isn't it? In this case, whenever we see anything else (like the aforementioned "CONTRACT INTERACTION") in the MetaMask (or some other wallet's) pop-up, we can say that the application was lazy about providing us with the human-readable information...

Comment: And regarding the last paragraph in your original answer: can't we, as EOAs, only interact with the `public` and `external` contract functions? Unless I'm wrong about that, the fact that I see a "CONTRACT INTERACTION" message instead of the function name cannot be caused by the fact that I'm calling a receive or fallback function.